# how does this mysql query work?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

My php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Less-1 SqL Injection master Course by Hitesh Choudhary</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../index.html_files/freemind2html.css" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style=" margin-top:70px;color:#FFF; font-size:23px; text-align:center">
            <h1><span class="style1">Welcome </span><font color="#FF0000">to SQL injection Master Course </font></h1>
            <h1><span class="style2">Lesson-1</span></h1>
            <h1><span class="style4">Hint : Error based string</span> <br>
                <font size="3" color="#666666">
                <?php
                    //including the Mysql connect parameters.
                    include("../sql-connections/sql-connect.php");

                    // take the variables
                    if(isset($_GET['id']))
                    {
                        $id=$_GET['id'];
                        //logging the connection parameters to a file for analysis.
                        //$fp=fopen('result.txt','a');
                        //fwrite($fp,'ID:'.$id."\n");
                        //fclose($fp);

                        // connectivity

                        $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 0,1";
                        $result=mysql_query($sql);
                        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

                            if($row)
                            {
                                echo '<font color= "#0000ff">';
                                echo 'Your Login name:'. $row['username'];
                                echo "<br>";
                                echo 'Your Password:' .$row['password'];
                                echo "</font>";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                echo '<font color= "#900">';
                                print_r(mysql_error());
                                echo "</font>";
                            }
                        }
                        else { echo "Please input the ID as parameter with numeric value";}

                ?>
                </font>
            </h1>
        </div>
        <img border="0" src="img1.gif" alt="funny" width="200" height="200">
        <div class="botton_fix">For more please visit : <a href="http://www.hiteshchoudhary.com" target="_blank">www.hiteshchoudhary.com</a></div>
        </br></br></br>
        <center>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to SQL inject this page using the following query

`localhost/example/Less-1/index.php?id=1 order by 100`

result is username:some and password:some

`localhost/example/Less-1/index.php?id=1`

result is username:some and password:some

I also checked with `$id=2,3,...` so on, and it works normally 
why does it work like that? I should get an error right?

Comment: I'd start by suggesting you not to use a deprecated API mysql_* but to use myslqi_* or even better PDO. Mysql_* API has been removed in PHP v7

Comment: I think you miss single quote. Try to ocalhost/example/Less-1/index.php?id=1'; DROP TABLE users; #

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, How you will be connect your db and use connection.. so i have wrote db connection in code .. Please try with it and let me know, if you get any issue. :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Less-1 SqL Injection master Course by Hitesh Choudhary</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../index.html_files/freemind2html.css" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style=" margin-top:70px;color:#FFF; font-size:23px; text-align:center">
            <h1><span class="style1">Welcome </span><font color="#FF0000">to SQL injection Master Course </font></h1>
            <h1><span class="style2">Lesson-1</span></h1>
            <h1><span class="style4">Hint : Error based string</span> <br>
                <font size="3" color="#666666">


                <?php


                 //   include("../sql-connections/sql-connect.php");


                if (!$link = mysql_connect('mysql_host', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password')) {
                        echo 'Could not connect to mysql';
                        exit;
                    }

                    if (!mysql_select_db('mysql_dbname', $link)) {
                        echo 'Could not select database';
                        exit;
                    }

                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='".$id."' LIMIT 0,1";
                    $result = mysql_query($sql, $link);

                    if (!$result) {
                        echo "DB Error, could not query the database\n";
                        echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
                        exit;
                    }

                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                        echo '<font color= "#0000ff">';
                                echo 'Your Login name:'. $row['username'];
                                echo "<br>";
                                echo 'Your Password:' .$row['password'];
                                echo "</font>"
                    }

                    mysql_free_result($result);




                ?>
                </font>
            </h1>
        </div>
        <img border="0" src="img1.gif" alt="funny" width="200" height="200">
        <div class="botton_fix">For more please visit : <a href="http://www.hiteshchoudhary.com" target="_blank">www.hiteshchoudhary.com</a></div>
        </br></br></br>
        <center>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Database query won't throw any error's in this case. You have to throw exception some thing like if the id not equal to session id

```
if ($_GET['id'] != $_SESSION['id']) {
   throw \Excetption("You don't have access.");
}
```